# Problems when filtering a row in a table

Tags: r

I'm having trouble filtering a table row, but I still don't understand why. Notice that I'm filtering by `Id`, `date2` and `Category`, but when I filter, it looks like it doesn't have any rows, but notice that from input information the corresponding row would have to be line 15 of `SPV`, however, it gives null return.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1<-structure(list(Id = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 1011, 
1011), date1 = structure(c(1641945600, 1641945600, 
1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 
1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 
1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 
1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641945600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), date2 = structure(c(1641340800, 
1641340800, 1641427200, 1641427200, 1641513600, 1641513600, 1641600000, 
1641600000, 1641686400, 1641686400, 1641772800, 1641772800, 1641859200, 
1641859200, 1641945600, 1641945600, 1641254400, 1641340800, 1641427200, 
1641513600, 1641600000, 1641686400, 1641772800, 1641859200, 1641945600), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Week = c("Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
 "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), Category = c("ABC", 
"EFG", "ABC", "EFG", "ABC", "EFG", "ABC", "EFG", "ABC", "EFG", 
"ABC", "EFG", "ABC", "EFG", "ABC", "EFG", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
"ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC"), DR1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 200, 350, 330, 400, 400, 332, 327.9, 383.6, 0), DRM0 = c(300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
0, 0, 200, 350, 330, 400, 400, 332, 327.9, 327.6, 323.75), DRM01 = c(300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
0, 0, 200, 350, 330, 400, 400, 332, 327.9, 340, 329.17), DRM02 = c(300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 0, 200, 350, 330, 400, 400, 332, 340, 340, 329.17), DRM03 = c(300, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 0, 200, 350, 330, 400, 400, 338.8, 340, 340, 329.17), DRM04 = c(300, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 0, 200, 350, 330, 400, 400, 338.8, 340, 340, 329.17)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


idd<-"4"
dmda<-"2022-01-12"
CategoryChosse<-"ABC"

 x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DRM0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x,Id, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Id,Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Id','Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DRM0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(Id:Category, DRM01_DRM01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
      > SPV
     Id      date1      date2      Week Category DRM01_DRM01_PV DRM02_DRM02_PV DRM03_DRM03_PV
1     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-05 Wednesday      ABC        150.000          0.000          0.000
2     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-05 Wednesday      EFG        150.000        150.000        150.000
3     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-06  Thursday      ABC          0.000          0.000          0.000
4     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-06  Thursday      EFG          0.000          0.000          0.000
5     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-07    Friday      ABC          0.000          0.000          0.000
6     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-07    Friday      EFG          0.000          0.000          0.000
7     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-08  Saturday      ABC          0.000          0.000          0.000
8     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-08  Saturday      EFG          0.000          0.000          0.000
9     4 2022-01-12 2022-01-09    Sunday      ABC          0.000          0.000          0.000
10    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-09    Sunday      EFG          0.000          0.000          0.000
11    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-10    Monday      ABC          0.000          0.000          0.000
12    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-10    Monday      EFG          0.000          0.000          0.000
13    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-11   Tuesday      ABC          0.000          0.000          0.000
14    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-11   Tuesday      EFG          0.000          0.000          0.000
15    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-12 Wednesday      ABC       -150.000          0.000          0.000
16    4 2022-01-12 2022-01-12 Wednesday      EFG       -150.000       -150.000       -150.000
17 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-04   Tuesday      ABC        221.800        221.800        221.800
18 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-05 Wednesday      ABC        185.415        185.415        185.415
19 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-06  Thursday      ABC        330.000        330.000        330.000
20 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-07    Friday      ABC        400.000        400.000        400.000
21 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-08  Saturday      ABC        400.000        400.000        400.000
22 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-09    Sunday      ABC        332.000        332.000        332.000
23 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-10    Monday      ABC        327.900        327.900        327.900
24 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-11   Tuesday      ABC        361.800        361.800        361.800
25 1011 2022-01-12 2022-01-12 Wednesday      ABC        164.585        164.585        164.585
   DRM04_DRM04_PV
1           0.000
2         125.000
3           0.000
4           0.000
5           0.000
6           0.000
7           0.000
8           0.000
9           0.000
10          0.000
11          0.000
12          0.000
13          0.000
14          0.000
15          0.000
16       -125.000
17        221.800
18        185.415
19        330.000
20        400.000
21        400.000
22        332.000
23        327.900
24        361.800
25        164.585

SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(Id==idd,date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) 


 > SPV
    [1] Id             date1          date2          Week           Category       DRM01_DRM01_PV DRM02_DRM02_PV
    [8] DRM03_DRM03_PV DRM04_DRM04_PV
```

Comment: It's probably occurring because the value you are testing the date against is a string rather than a date. Try converting `dmda` to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach, writing out what's already been outlined in the comments. I used `ymd` from `lubridate` to convert the date string to a date object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

idd<-4
dmda<-ymd("2022-01-12")
CategoryChosse<-"ABC"

df1 %>% 
  filter(Id == idd, date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse)
# A tibble: 1 x 11
     Id date1               date2               Week  Category   DR1  DRM0 DRM01
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4 2022-01-12 00:00:00 2022-01-12 00:00:00 Wedn… ABC          0     0     0
# … with 3 more variables: DRM02 <dbl>, DRM03 <dbl>, DRM04 <dbl>
```